# javascript data search from html table heading data not show

Tags: javascript, html

i create the table and search option code get form  https://www.w3schools.com/ 
my table one extra row taken for table data more clearance

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name OF LOCO">

<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped" align="center" style="text-align:center;">

  <tr class="header">
    <th style="text-align:center;" rowspan="2">Loco</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;" rowspan="2">TFR</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;" rowspan="2">TRCTION MOTOR</th>
    <th  style="text-align:center;" colspan="3">Starting Current(Amps)</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;" rowspan="2">Countinuous Current</th>
  </tr>

  <tr class="header">
    <td>2 min</td>
    <td>10 min</td>
    <td>60 min</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>WAP 1</td>
    <td>HETT 3900</td>
    <td>TAO 659</td>
    <td>1100</td>
    <td>1000</td>
     <td>840</td>
    <td>750 Amps</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>WAP4</td>
    <td>HETT 5400</td>
    <td>HS 10250</td>
    <td>1250</td>
    <td>1100</td>
     <td>960</td>
    <td>900 Amps</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>WAM4 6P</td>
    <td>HETT 3900</td>
    <td>TAO 659</td>
    <td>1100</td>
    <td>1000</td>
     <td>840</td>
    <td>750 Amps</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

that's my table and search code

```
 <script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>
```

normally it's seen
[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjcB2.png)
abnormality/when i search anything like that

[image]

now seach time data show but it's show but it's start form span row. please help

Comment: Can you kindly clarify your question? What you actually want to do here Explain.

Comment: the result show after header . when i search it's show data from header

Comment: So you want to remove the header right?

Comment: yes now i added normal look of my table so essay to understand when i type for search it's show on there

Comment: Why you put 2 different headers in the table??

Comment: for classify three different condition(2min , 10 min,60min) in a same row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please put this code.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("tbody");
  tr = table.getElementsByClassName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name OF LOCO">

<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped" align="center" style="text-align:center;">
<thead>
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="text-align:center;" >Loco</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;" >TFR</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;">TRCTION MOTOR</th>
    <th  style="text-align:center;">Starting Current(Amps)
      <table width="100%">
        <tr>
    <td>2 min</td>
    <td>10 min</td>
    <td>60 min</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;">Countinuous Current</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">
  <tr class="tr">
    <td>WAP 1</td>
    <td>HETT 3900</td>
    <td>TAO 659</td>
    <td>
      <table width="100%">
          <tr>
    <td>1100</td>
    <td>1000</td>
     <td>840</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>750 Amps</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr">
    <td>WAP 2</td>
    <td>HETT 3900</td>
    <td>TAO 659</td>
    <td>
      <table width="100%">
          <tr>
    <td>1100</td>
    <td>1000</td>
     <td>840</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>750 Amps</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr">
    <td>WAP 3</td>
    <td>HETT 3900</td>
    <td>TAO 659</td>
    <td>
     <table width="100%">
          <tr>
    <td>1100</td>
    <td>1000</td>
     <td>840</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>750 Amps</td>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
  
  </table>
```